# Adding a one to many relationship on a bitmask field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using an integer column in my model as a bitmask to store different potential properties about an object. I'm using a mask because there's a fixed number of categories that will never change so storing it as a record in a database isn't accurate.  However, there's potentially an unlimited number of subcategories that are related to the categories.  I'm having trouble understanding how this association would be set up.

Let's say I have a product model that has 2 types of cost categories such as manufacture and installation. Each cost category will have at least 1 subcategory that is what went into the manufacture, what went into installation.  For example, manufacture might include the buying of a particular part but that is not part of the installation.  The problem is, how can a one-to-many relationship be set up between manufacture and a subcategory?

I have set up the product model to use bitmasks with this gem: https://github.com/joelmoss/bitmask_attributes.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  bitmask :cost_categories, as: [:manufacture, :installation]
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to ...
end
```

I can easily add or check categories but I don't know how I can relate `:manufacture` or `:installation` to a separate model.

I would like to be able to do something like this `Product.first.cost_categories.first.subcategories`

How can I add a subcategory relationship between the different bitmasked attributes? Is this possible?